# Script to turn flagged emails into reminders

Tags: mail.app, applescript

I am looking for a script that will recognize when an email is flagged and then turn it into a Reminder using the Reminders app.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got the automator to filter the the flagged mail using the action [Find Mail Item (Message is marked with - flagged)]. But there isn't much you can do with the mail items except have them pop up on Mail using action [Display Mail Messages].

Then I found a script here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3435695?start=0&tstart=0
that takes mail and automatically generates reminder from Mail.

I haven't tried it through myself. But hopefully that gives you a start.

Comment: I think this is close, and I really appreciate your help. It seems that this creates the reminder in iCal as opposed to the Reminders.App

Comment: Actually, It does create the reminder, but not from a flagged message. So we are really close. I cannot figure out a way to flag the message and then run the script. Thoughts?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any automator action to extract data from the Mail items. In fact there wasn't any menu item in mail. Reminder creation in mail is contextual. If there was a date in the Mail item body then hovering the mouse over it allows the user to create a Reminder. I don't know how that would translate into an Applescript though.